# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tinkerpop/blueprints/impls/orient/OrientGraphFactory

Tags: linux, maven, orientdb, java

I have some problem when I want to connect to Orientdb databases.

```
OrientGraphFactory connect = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:/opt/orientdb/databases/fulltext5", "admin", "admin");
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tinkerpop/blueprints/impls/orient/OrientGraphFactory
at edu.ucla.sspace.doc.reader.MyUI.init(MyUI.java:36)
at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:682)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:214)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
```

But main things that i have  `
        
            com.orientechnologies
            orientdb-graphdb
            2.2.13

And `com/tinkerpop/blueprints/impls/orient/OrientGraphFactory is existence in my jar file:
[image]

Comment: Would you post the MYUI code, on line 36 its says there is an error

Comment: OrientGraphFactory connect = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:/opt/orientdb/databases/fulltext5", "admin", "admin");
@Aaron this code. which connect to orientdb

Comment: do you use maven or gradle to manage dependencies? Take a look about transitive deps : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.orientechnologies/orientdb-graphdb/2.2.13

Comment: moreover, you are running a webapp deployed under tomcat. Does the WAR contain all needed jars under lib? This seems only a classpath problem. You should understand WHERE are you messing up the classpath  , probably when you assemble the WAR or when you run the webapp inside the IDE

Answer (score 2):

OK, I solve my problem by downloading all needed jars and paste it to web-inf/lib folder. I really don't know why it's need there, cause I use maven dependencies, but doesn't matter. It's work. And I add to classpath my maven jars, it also doesn't help.

Comment: Can you post your pom? Are you packaging your app as a war? How are you running the app? Are you deploying the war, or run a mvn jetty:run, or run  it inside the IDE? Details matter.